# Mac mini crashing multiple times a day

Tags: macos, mac-mini, crash

My Mac mini keeps crashing multiple times a day. I have no idea why it happens. It seems to happen at random. Here's the crash report:

```
Anonymous UUID:       331DE8F9-6070-3C48-F305-09EE633FFF3F

Fri Apr 24 13:12:24 2015

*** Panic Report ***
panic(cpu 4 caller 0xffffff802d617cc2): Kernel trap at 0xffffff802d30e254, type 14=page fault, registers:
CR0: 0x0000000080010033, CR2: 0xffffff81cb337000, CR3: 0x000000000cd7c01f, CR4: 0x00000000001606e0
RAX: 0x0e0e0e0e0e0e0e0e, RBX: 0xffffff81cb330400, RCX: 0xffffff81cb337008, RDX: 0x00000000eeeeeeee
RSP: 0xffffff82175d2ce0, RBP: 0xffffff82175d2d50, RSI: 0xffffff81cb330000, RDI: 0xffffff8310326adc
R8:  0xffffff831032a0e0, R9:  0xffffff840e326adc, R10: 0xffffff8310326be8, R11: 0x0f0f0f0f0f0f0f0f
R12: 0xfffffea74350f000, R13: 0xffffff81cb330000, R14: 0xffffff80733570a0, R15: 0x000000000c0028ec
RFL: 0x0000000000010202, RIP: 0xffffff802d30e254, CS:  0x0000000000000008, SS:  0x0000000000000010
Fault CR2: 0xffffff81cb337000, Error code: 0x0000000000000002, Fault CPU: 0x4

Backtrace (CPU 4), Frame : Return Address
0xffffff82175d2990 : 0xffffff802d52bda1 
0xffffff82175d2a10 : 0xffffff802d617cc2 
0xffffff82175d2bd0 : 0xffffff802d634b73 
0xffffff82175d2bf0 : 0xffffff802d30e254 
0xffffff82175d2d50 : 0xffffff802d58f4e1 
0xffffff82175d2dc0 : 0xffffff802d58dff5 
0xffffff82175d2df0 : 0xffffff802d590591 
0xffffff82175d2e30 : 0xffffff802d5952bf 
0xffffff82175d2fe0 : 0xffffff802d5c464e 
0xffffff82175d3380 : 0xffffff802d5936d3 
0xffffff82175d33e0 : 0xffffff802dae7441 
0xffffff82175d3500 : 0xffffff802dae7741 
0xffffff82175d3530 : 0xffffff7faf80e571 
0xffffff82175d3560 : 0xffffff7faf86905f 
0xffffff82175d3590 : 0xffffff7faf7d7985 
0xffffff82175d35b0 : 0xffffff7faf80cfcc 
0xffffff82175d35d0 : 0xffffff7faf7f0c5b 
0xffffff82175d3600 : 0xffffff7faf86c714 
0xffffff82175d37d0 : 0xffffff7faf7ef358 
0xffffff82175d3840 : 0xffffff7faf7eef9c 
0xffffff82175d3860 : 0xffffff7faf7f09ab 
0xffffff82175d3880 : 0xffffff7faf7dd495 
0xffffff82175d38d0 : 0xffffff7faf868050 
0xffffff82175d3910 : 0xffffff7faf8629aa 
0xffffff82175d39c0 : 0xffffff7faf7dc6fd 
0xffffff82175d39f0 : 0xffffff7faf7dcab9 
0xffffff82175d3a20 : 0xffffff7faf7ea2bc 
0xffffff82175d3a70 : 0xffffff7faf867759 
0xffffff82175d3aa0 : 0xffffff7faf7dada2 
0xffffff82175d3b30 : 0xffffff802db00d52 
0xffffff82175d3b60 : 0xffffff802db01949 
0xffffff82175d3bc0 : 0xffffff802daff0c3 
0xffffff82175d3d00 : 0xffffff802d5e21e7 
0xffffff82175d3e10 : 0xffffff802d53000c 
0xffffff82175d3e40 : 0xffffff802d5149f3 
0xffffff82175d3e90 : 0xffffff802d52531d 
0xffffff82175d3f10 : 0xffffff802d6031ea 
0xffffff82175d3fb0 : 0xffffff802d635396 
      Kernel Extensions in backtrace:
         com.apple.iokit.IOAcceleratorFamily2(156.14)[BE7D765B-49C1-34F9-B75E-3EAF8A4062A3]@0xffffff7faf7d6000->0xffffff7faf844fff
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily(2.9)[52E715FC-521D-3869-B2EA-5228FA4BEA34]@0xffffff7fadd24000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOGraphicsFamily(2.4.1)[82EAD591-67E3-39CB-A232-A8095CA30E92]@0xffffff7fadfef000
         com.apple.driver.AppleIntelHD4000Graphics(10.0.6)[51B5D3C1-1319-3470-877F-B988299234BF]@0xffffff7faf853000->0xffffff7faf8aefff
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOSurface(97.4)[A4AE35B7-0C17-38F2-AD0D-A4C4B40196FB]@0xffffff7fae535000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily(2.9)[52E715FC-521D-3869-B2EA-5228FA4BEA34]@0xffffff7fadd24000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOGraphicsFamily(2.4.1)[82EAD591-67E3-39CB-A232-A8095CA30E92]@0xffffff7fadfef000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOAcceleratorFamily2(156.14)[BE7D765B-49C1-34F9-B75E-3EAF8A4062A3]@0xffffff7faf7d6000

BSD process name corresponding to current thread: WindowServer

Mac OS version:
14D136

Kernel version:
Darwin Kernel Version 14.3.0: Mon Mar 23 11:59:05 PDT 2015; root:xnu-2782.20.48~5/RELEASE_X86_64
Kernel UUID: 4B3A11F4-77AA-3D27-A22D-81A1BC5B504D
Kernel slide:     0x000000002d200000
Kernel text base: 0xffffff802d400000
__HIB  text base: 0xffffff802d300000
System model name: Macmini6,2 (Mac-F65AE981FFA204ED)

System uptime in nanoseconds: 138556446744908
last loaded kext at 94990677546147: com.apple.driver.AppleUSBCDC    4.3.3b1 (addr 0xffffff7fafe05000, size 20480)
last unloaded kext at 95050708095644: com.apple.driver.AppleUSBCDC  4.3.3b1 (addr 0xffffff7fafe05000, size 16384)
loaded kexts:
org.virtualbox.kext.VBoxNetAdp  4.3.26
org.virtualbox.kext.VBoxNetFlt  4.3.26
org.virtualbox.kext.VBoxUSB 4.3.26
org.virtualbox.kext.VBoxDrv 4.3.26
com.intel.kext.intelhaxm    1.0.5
com.shapeservices.msm.driver.MSMFramebuffer 3.3.2
com.shapeservices.msm.driver.MSMVideoDevice 3.3.2
com.apple.filesystems.msdosfs   1.10
com.apple.driver.AppleBluetoothMultitouch   85.3
com.apple.driver.ApplePlatformEnabler   2.2.0d4
com.apple.driver.AGPM   110.19.5
com.apple.driver.X86PlatformShim    1.0.0
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothSerialManager    4.3.4f4
com.apple.filesystems.autofs    3.0
com.apple.driver.AppleOSXWatchdog   1
com.apple.driver.AppleMikeyHIDDriver    124
com.apple.driver.AppleHDA   272.18
com.apple.driver.AppleUpstreamUserClient    3.6.1
com.apple.driver.AppleMCCSControl   1.2.11
com.apple.iokit.IOUserEthernet  1.0.1
com.apple.Dont_Steal_Mac_OS_X   7.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelHD4000Graphics   10.0.6
com.apple.driver.AppleHWAccess  1
com.apple.driver.AppleMikeyDriver   272.18
com.apple.iokit.BroadcomBluetoothHostControllerUSBTransport 4.3.4f4
com.apple.driver.AppleHV    1
com.apple.driver.AppleSMCPDRC   1.0.0
com.apple.driver.AudioAUUC  1.70
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelFramebufferCapri 10.0.6
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelSlowAdaptiveClocking 4.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleLPC   1.7.3
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltIP 2.0.2
com.apple.driver.AppleIRController  327.5
com.apple.AppleFSCompression.AppleFSCompressionTypeDataless 1.0.0d1
com.apple.AppleFSCompression.AppleFSCompressionTypeZlib 1.0.0d1
com.apple.BootCache 36
com.apple.driver.XsanFilter 404
com.apple.iokit.IOAHCIBlockStorage  2.7.1
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBHub    705.4.2
com.apple.driver.AppleSDXC  1.6.5
com.apple.iokit.AppleBCM5701Ethernet    10.1.3
com.apple.driver.AppleFWOHCI    5.5.2
com.apple.driver.AirPort.Brcm4360   930.37.3
com.apple.driver.AppleAHCIPort  3.1.2
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBEHCI   705.4.14
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBXHCI   710.4.11
com.apple.driver.AppleRTC   2.0
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIButtons   3.1
com.apple.driver.AppleHPET  1.8
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBIOS    2.1
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIEC    3.1
com.apple.driver.AppleAPIC  1.7
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelCPUPowerManagementClient 218.0.0
com.apple.nke.applicationfirewall   161
com.apple.security.quarantine   3
com.apple.security.TMSafetyNet  8
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelCPUPowerManagement   218.0.0
com.apple.driver.IOBluetoothHIDDriver   4.3.4f4
com.apple.driver.AppleMultitouchDriver  263.9.1
com.apple.iokit.IOSerialFamily  11
com.apple.kext.triggers 1.0
com.apple.driver.DspFuncLib 272.18
com.apple.kext.OSvKernDSPLib    1.15
com.apple.iokit.IOSurface   97.4
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothHostControllerUSBTransport   4.3.4f4
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothFamily   4.3.4f4
com.apple.driver.AppleHDAController 272.18
com.apple.iokit.IOHDAFamily 272.18
com.apple.iokit.IONDRVSupport   2.4.1
com.apple.driver.X86PlatformPlugin  1.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBusController   1.0.13d1
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBUserClient 705.4.0
com.apple.iokit.IOAcceleratorFamily2    156.14
com.apple.AppleGraphicsDeviceControl    3.10.22
com.apple.iokit.IOGraphicsFamily    2.4.1
com.apple.iokit.IOSlowAdaptiveClockingFamily    1.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleSMC   3.1.9
com.apple.iokit.IOFireWireIP    2.2.6
com.apple.driver.IOPlatformPluginFamily 5.9.1d7
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBusPCI  1.0.12d1
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBAudio  295.23
com.apple.iokit.IOAudioFamily   203.3
com.apple.vecLib.kext   1.2.0
com.apple.iokit.IOSCSIBlockCommandsDevice   3.7.5
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBMassStorageClass   3.7.2
com.apple.iokit.IOSCSIArchitectureModelFamily   3.7.5
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBMergeNub   705.4.0
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBHIDDriver  705.4.0
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBComposite  705.4.9
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltDPInAdapter    4.0.6
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltDPAdapterFamily    4.0.6
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltPCIDownAdapter 2.0.2
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltNHI    3.1.7
com.apple.iokit.IOThunderboltFamily 4.2.2
com.apple.iokit.IOEthernetAVBController 1.0.3b3
com.apple.iokit.IOFireWireFamily    4.5.6
com.apple.iokit.IO80211Family   730.60
com.apple.driver.mDNSOffloadUserClient  1.0.1b8
com.apple.iokit.IONetworkingFamily  3.2
com.apple.iokit.IOAHCIFamily    2.7.5
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBFamily 720.4.4
com.apple.driver.AppleEFINVRAM  2.0
com.apple.driver.AppleEFIRuntime    2.0
com.apple.iokit.IOHIDFamily 2.0.0
com.apple.iokit.IOSMBusFamily   1.1
com.apple.security.sandbox  300.0
com.apple.kext.AppleMatch   1.0.0d1
com.apple.driver.AppleKeyStore  2
com.apple.driver.AppleMobileFileIntegrity   1.0.5
com.apple.driver.AppleCredentialManager 1.0
com.apple.driver.DiskImages 396
com.apple.iokit.IOStorageFamily 2.0
com.apple.iokit.IOReportFamily  31
com.apple.driver.AppleFDEKeyStore   28.30
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIPlatform  3.1
com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily 2.9
com.apple.iokit.IOACPIFamily    1.4
com.apple.kec.corecrypto    1.0
com.apple.kec.Libm  1
com.apple.kec.pthread   1

System Profile:
AirPort: spairport_wireless_card_type_airport_extreme (0x14E4, 0x10E), Broadcom BCM43xx 1.0 (7.15.166.24.3)
Bluetooth: Version 4.3.4f4 15601, 3 services, 27 devices, 1 incoming serial ports
Thunderbolt Bus: Mac mini, Apple Inc., 23.4
Memory Module: BANK 0/DIMM0, 8 GB, DDR3, 1600 MHz, 0x802C, 0x31364B544631473634485A2D314736453220
Memory Module: BANK 1/DIMM0, 8 GB, DDR3, 1600 MHz, 0x802C, 0x31364B544631473634485A2D314736453220
USB Device: USB Flash Drive
USB Device: Hub
USB Device: Hub
USB Device: Hub
USB Device: IR Receiver
USB Device: BRCM20702 Hub
USB Device: Bluetooth USB Host Controller
USB Device: USB 2.0 Hub [Safe]
USB Device: DCP-J125
USB Device: Microsoft® 2.4GHz Transceiver v7.0
USB Device: USB 2.0 Hub [MTT]
USB Device: iPhone
USB Device: Miscellaneous Device
Serial ATA Device: APPLE HDD HTS541010A9E662, 1 TB
Model: Macmini6,2, BootROM MM61.0106.B04, 4 processors, Intel Core i7, 2.6 GHz, 16 GB, SMC 2.8f1
Network Service: Ethernet, Ethernet, en0
Network Service: Wi-Fi, AirPort, en1
Graphics: Intel HD Graphics 4000, Intel HD Graphics 4000, Built-In
Unable to gather system configuration information.Model: Macmini6,2, BootROM MM61.0106.B04, 4 processors, Intel Core i7, 2.6 GHz, 16 GB, SMC 2.8f1
Graphics: Intel HD Graphics 4000, Intel HD Graphics 4000, Built-In
Memory Module: BANK 0/DIMM0, 8 GB, DDR3, 1600 MHz, 0x802C, 0x31364B544631473634485A2D314736453220
Memory Module: BANK 1/DIMM0, 8 GB, DDR3, 1600 MHz, 0x802C, 0x31364B544631473634485A2D314736453220
AirPort: spairport_wireless_card_type_airport_extreme (0x14E4, 0x10E), Broadcom BCM43xx 1.0 (7.15.166.24.3)
Bluetooth: Version 4.3.4f4 15601, 3 services, 27 devices, 1 incoming serial ports
Network Service: Ethernet, Ethernet, en0
Network Service: Wi-Fi, AirPort, en1
Serial ATA Device: APPLE HDD HTS541010A9E662, 1 TB
USB Device: USB Flash Drive
USB Device: Hub
USB Device: Hub
USB Device: IR Receiver
USB Device: BRCM20702 Hub
USB Device: Bluetooth USB Host Controller
USB Device: Hub
USB Device: USB 2.0 Hub [Safe]
USB Device: USB 2.0 Hub [MTT]
USB Device: iPhone
USB Device: Miscellaneous Device
USB Device: DCP-J125
USB Device: Microsoft® 2.4GHz Transceiver v7.0
Thunderbolt Bus: Mac mini, Apple Inc., 23.4
```

Comment: First thing to look for when a Mac crashes is anything installed by microsoft. I'd uninstall anything relating to the "Microsoft® 2.4GHz Transceiver v7.0" (whatever that is). I'd also look into the 'virtualbox' kernel extensions.

Comment: I have a microsoft wireless keybaord and that's the wireless receiver... regarding virtualbox, I don't see how that could be causing any problem...

Comment: Virtualbox has installed a kernel extension which has root access to your mac. Any 3rd party kernel extensions should be suspect if you are crashing frequently as a kosher Mac does not crash in my experience. If the microsoft keyboard requires no additional driver and uses the supplied apple drivers then it's probably fine - if it installs a driver then I'd remove the driver and see where that gets you.

Answer (score 1):

I found that kernal panics and complete freezes often happen due to bad drivers, usually third party. You could try to remove devices like external bluetooth dongles or external wifi adapters for a while to see if it keeps crashing, and if you find the device causing it perhaps look for different drivers. I hope this helps you find the cause more quickly, as crash reports are hard to read and often incomplete.